# Magento2 I need to display order details in my custom admin grid

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 , in my admin grid display order table data.. How to display this?
Can you give my any suggestion please.

Comment: What you want to show there?

Comment: I want to display order id ,purchase date and status.. in my custom grid